# Chi-squared distribution/ probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I want to compute $P(Z \geq 3.26)$ with  Z ~ $ \chi^2(4 )$ 
The tables only contain the  p-values.

For example: https://www.medcalc.org/manual/chi-square-table.php

Comment: Do you mean $3260$ or $3.260=3.26$?

Comment: @Bartek: I mean 3.26

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid that you can't find the answer in the tables. Using WolframAlpha/Mathematica function:
$$\textrm{1 - CDF[ChiSquareDistribution[4], 3.26]}$$
The answer turns out to be about $0.515295$. You could have technically find this value in the tables but you would have to have p-value of $0.484705=1-0.515295$ (or something approximate like $0.5$) in the columns. With current version of your tables you can only tell that the value you are looking for is between $0.025=1-0.975$ and $0.8=1-0.2$ as your number is between $0.484$ and $5.989$.

Comment: Thank you very much. That helped a lot:)